# Will the choice of prescaler and period while configuring a timer influence the MCU load and power consumption?

Tags: microcontroller, timer, power-consumption

Let us say we want to configure a 16-bit timer to generate an interrupt every 1 second with a clock running at 8 MHz.

We can use several pair of values for the period and prescaler. Let us take the two extremes:

- prescaler = 125 and period = 64000,
- prescaler = 64000 and period = 125.

Is it better to take one of the two pair of values regarding the MCU load and power consumption?

Comment: I would not think of a measurable difference, but it would be an interesting experiment which is easy to perform.

Comment: When each FF toggles, you'll have about 1mA of shoot-thru current for about 100 picoseconds (your mileage will vary, based on VDD, circuit, technology, etc)

Comment: The biggest win would be not clocking your entire chip at 8 MHz when not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Probably no difference at all, since the same flip-flop design is likely used in both places. Whichever way you configure it, you have the same number of flip-flops toggling at the same rates.

Comment: What is confusing me is that, for one period, the counter register will be written N times, N being the period value. As a consequence there will be less register writings than if we took a higher value for the period.

Comment: @Mat.R the prescalars are effectively counter registers too.  There may be a tiny difference, but it's really unlikely to be of consequenece.